# Is there a way to join multiple vlookups?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I have a spreadsheet I am entering information from a fundraiser in.  I have many parts of it done and it seems like what I'm running into should be easier. I have 3 rows set up for each fundraising program, the first row contains a few pieces of incidental information and then a series of dates/times/dollar amounts.  I need to search through this range for every dollar amount that came in at, for example, 7:00 am and add them together.  I would like this list to come in starting at L1 in the sample sheet and correspond to the list of times in column K.

I will also need to total all the contributions based on a topic which is the cell under the title of the program - but I should be able to figure that out once I move on to it.

A sample sheet is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Kg7XhIgzI0o0uIuGg0RTzv7j_bne8pk6DUwSecIXa9E/edit?usp=sharing

I have tried a variety of formulas using ArrayFormula, VLOOKUP, and filter.  I've found examples online using each of those functions that seemed like they should work but didn't.  One stopped at the first result it came to and another looked like it was creating a list of what it was found in the cell instead of adding them together.

My current unsuccessful code is:

```
=vlookup(K1, $H$46:$J$164, 2, 0)
```

This appears as if it is stopping after encountering the first 0.  It's definitely not adding in cell I50

I expect the results for 7:00 am to be $406 but I get $0.

Comment: how did you calculate 406? it shouldn't be 306?

Comment: You're correct, must have been a typo.

Answer (score 0):

paste in **L1** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TO_TEXT(K1:K35), TO_TEXT(QUERY({
 FILTER(H46:I, MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A4:A"&ROWS(A46:A)+3)), 4)=0);
 FILTER(K46:L, MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A4:A"&ROWS(A46:A)+3)), 4)=0);
 FILTER(N46:O, MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A4:A"&ROWS(A46:A)+3)), 4)=0);
 FILTER(Q46:R, MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A4:A"&ROWS(A46:A)+3)), 4)=0)},
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col2)''", 0)), 2, 0), 0)*1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks!  That was a more complicated formula than I was expecting.